# Ideas on making a search in Backbone.js application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

***what I've got now***

---

- Product model/view;
- Products collection;
- Products list view;
- Quite straightforward pager view;
- and of course a router;

*router*

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'list',
        '!/products': 'list',
        '!/products/page/:page': 'list'
        //, '!/search/:term/:page': 'some_handler'
    }
});

appRouter.on('route:list', function(page) {
    renderProductsList(page);
});
```

[Pager and its template can be found there](http://jsfiddle.net/challenger/SVLJs/2/)

```
var renderProductsList = function(page) {
    require(['collections/ProductsList', 'views/ProductListView', 'views/PagerView'], 
    function(ProductsList, ProductListView, PagerView) {
        var p = page ? parseInt(page, 10) : 1;
        var productsList = new ProductsList();
        productsList.fetch({
            success: function() {
                var $container = $("#content-region");
                $container.html(new ProductListView({
                    model: productsList,
                    page: p
                }).el);

                // attach pager
                var $pager = new PagerView({
                    // pager options
                }).$el;
                // ...
            },
            error: function() {
                // handle the error
            }
        });
    });
}
```

---

***Questions***

- Should I reuse `renderProductsList` method?
- I know functions like `where`, `filter` can be called on collections? How can I use that?
- Should I cache fetched results?
- How do I reuse my pager? Should I pass url pattern within `options` argument?
- Well... how do I rebuild my application to make it possible to search by, for example, this route `!/search/:term/:page`

---

**I'm not interested in using `Backbone.Pagination`**

Comment: Yeah, you can do whatever you want, but... what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to perform a search with a given term and use product list view for that. Don't know whether I should filter cached data on a client side or hit server per each request? I just need to know what others do in that case.

Comment: I'd say go with server side filtering. After all you want users to see what actually is there and you can always add caching on server side if needed. Don't preoptimize.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you just have a list of products, and would like to create some filters. Thus you're wondering how to do it. Well I'd say it depends on a lot of factors.
Do you, in any case, fetch everything at start? If yes, well, of course you'll only use JS. If not:
Cache the results? Well, I have no idea how you'd do that, or it'd really by a bother I guess. Still it depends on:
Is the amount of data transferred big?..
There are quite a lot of things to take into account, and the problem begins at the router. With only one route called (Backbone absolutely can't call several routes, it will stop at the first pattern matched, independent of the number of routers you have), you'll have to load your search page, do your filter, and go to the correct page.
tl;dr: I think we don't have enough information to really help you.

As for how to use `where` and such, I think [Backbone's doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) is pretty complete on the subject (I don't really know what do you want to know about these).